# Analysis: Interior Points and Derivatives

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I am trying to prove that if $x$ is an interior point, then $f'(x)$ exists or is infinite where $f_+'(x)=f_-'(x)$.

This seems intuitive, as for any function, the derivative only exists or is infinite where this is true, but I'm not sure how to prove this using interior points.

Comment: Does "exists" mean "exists finitely"? Does "infinite" mean a definite signed infinity or unsigned infinity? Are the left and right derivatives allowed to have signed infinite values, so that $f'_{+}(x) = f'_{-}(x)$ is true if each equals $+\infty$ or if each equals $-\infty$?

Comment: What are the assumption on $f(x)$?